# didSet usage recommendation?

Tags: ios, swift2, didset

Assume I have a video player with resize button for full/small screen. Writing resizing (frames, autolayout constants, and others) codes in a variable called isVideoFullScreen variable's didSet and just calling for IBAction button ->

```
isVideoFullScreen = !isVideoFullScreen
```

And yes I'm using isVideoFullScreen variable for some other reasons.

tl;dr if possible, writing some bunch of codes that depends on a variable, is it good to write them under variable's didSet?

Comment: I think you meant isVideoFullScreen = !isVideoFullScreen

Comment: just fixed, thank you

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what didSet is for

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. However much code you want to put in the `didSet` closure is up to you. However keep in mind it might be better to place your resizing code in another function and call that function from `didSet`.